# Use git-filter-repo to filter out a list of files in commits which are not descendants of a given commit

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

It seems `git filter-branch` is deprecated and `git-filter-repo` should be used instead. I am using `git filter-branch --index-filter` to remove a list of files from commits which are not descendants of a given commit. This is done like

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git merge-base --is-ancestor aaaaaaaa $GIT_COMMIT ; if [ $? -eq 1 ] ; then git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch a.txt b.txt c.txt ; fi' HEAD
```

So `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt` are removed from any commit being not descendant of `aaaaaaaa`. Is there any way to achieve this with `git-filter-repo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `git filter-branch` for what it's good for, use `git filter-repo` for what it's better for. I doubt it's possible to make filter-repo do what you're after at all, or at any rate not nearly so well.

I recommend simply ignoring most of the criticisms leveled at git filter-branch, particularly the ones in the filter-repo readme, as regrettably overstated. Put `export FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1` in `~/.bashrc` and be done with it.